# Trying to figure out how to wire up a wall socket that has 2 extra switches

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am replacing a standard wall socket to a switch with 2 extra buttons but I'm unsure the best and safest way to provide power to the 2 extra switches. My idea is to use electrical screw connectors so each screw point will have no more than 3 wires going into them because I doubt 4 wires would fit in there. Does anyone have any experience wiring this sort of configuration? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I like to have as few connection points as possible.  There are electrical connectors that will take more than three wires if they are listed/label for that.  The size of the receptacle/switch box will be important also, because small ones can only have so many wires in them.

Comment: It should arrive tomorrow morning so Ill check. Thanks mate

Comment: I'd avoid mixing stranded & solid in the same terminal - the terminal strip would be a good way to separate that if you have to. Otherwise, some terminals can easily take 4 solid wires, robustly. *Some can't*. I'd wait for a visual before making the call.